# ionic File download using FTP

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have a problem with the FTP plugin (http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ftp/). I want to download a series of files from an FTP one by one and once a file is downloaded the application should read the file and insert the data into a database. The problem is that the application reads the file before it is downloaded 100% and I do not know how to fix it.

According to the documentation, the download percentage is returned, but I do not know how to launch the function once it reaches 100% (resDL=1).

This is my code:

```
this.ftp.download(pathLocal+'lecturaData/'+filename, filename)
            .then((resDL: any)=>{
                if (resDL == 1) {
                    return this.FromFileToBBDD(this.file.externalDataDirectory+'lecturaData/', filename);
                }
            })
          .catch((error: any) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: could you log your resDL  and post here?

Comment: Hi, in the documentation says that "The arg 0, 0.1xx, 0.2xx … 1 means the upload percent. When it reach 1, means success."

resDL is that arg, the return is a number but never is 1...

Comment: Yeah, I looked at the docs for the plugin but I couldn't make much of it. If you could just console.log(resDL), we could make more sense out of it. If it never is 1 then there is no way it can enter a conditional statement. So, could you share the exact output from the log?

Comment: This is the output: 0.023216631 The number is different each time I try, for example 0.011608316 or 0.013552452...